# Error in compiling main .tex file when separate section file is included

Tags: pdftex, compiling, input, thesis

I want to use this LaTeX [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/universiti-malaya-thesis-template/kbdmvkbnjchb) for writing my thesis. I downloaded the files and tried to run it using Texstudio (with MikTex distribution) on my new machine, without modifying anything in the original files obtained from the website. However, the main *.tex* file failed to compile and the error message I got is "*pdflatex.exe did not succeed*".

**The main .tex file** contains several sections written in a separate *.tex* file, as shown in the following code snippet:

```
\documentclass[english,singlespacedlisttitles]{umalayathesis}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names,rgb]{xcolor}


% Useful for including code listings
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,columns=fullflexible,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\SingleSpacing,
        texcsstyle=*\bfseries\color{NavyBlue},
        commentstyle=\itshape\color{PaleVioletRed4},
        frame=single,framesep=6pt,
        framexleftmargin=6pt,framexrightmargin=6pt,
        xleftmargin=12pt,xrightmargin=12pt,
        breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=true,
%        aboveskip=-1.5\onelineskip
}

\title{The umalayathesis \LaTeX{} Document Class}

\begin{document}

\input{umalayathesis-howtouse}
\input{sample-chap-intro}
\input{sample-chap-dummy}

\end{document}
```

I believe some problem occurs in the part where **\input{...}** is present the main *.tex* file. As I comment out the lines as follows:

```
%\input{umalayathesis-howtouse}
%\input{sample-chap-intro}
\input{sample-chap-dummy}
```

the main *.tex* file is successfully compiled without any error.

Note that the sub-file **sample-chap-dummy.tex** is written as follows:

```
%!TEX ROOT = thesis.tex
\chapter{Dummy Chapter}

Hello!!\index{furball}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\centering Test 3
\caption{Let's see. What have we got here?}
\end{figure}
```

However, the main file fails to compile again when I tried to insert some inline formula ($...$) in the subfile above, for example:

```
%!TEX ROOT = thesis.tex
\chapter{Dummy Chapter}

Hello!!\index{furball}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\centering Test 3
\caption{Let's see. What have we got here?}
\end{figure}

%The main file fails to compile when I added the following line:
$a=bc$
```

I believe the main problem lies in my current machine, because I had no problem compiling the files in my old machine.

On my current machine, I can compile most of the .tex files without any problem, except where the main .tex file includes some sections written in separate tex files. Hope someone can help me with this! Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello @Elina, and welcome! Rather than show input that *does* work, could you edit the question to show a version that fails? The problem is probably in umalaythesis though, since your document looks pretty simple.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau Hi. Thank you, I have edited the question according to your suggestion. I doubt that the problem is in umalayathesis, because I have no problem compiling the same files in my other machine. The files only fail to work in my current working machine. I have no idea why. I just installed MikTex (with complete packages) and TeXstudio on my current (new) machine yesterday. I have no problem compiling most other .tex files, except this one where the \input{...} presents.

Comment: I downloaded umalayathesis-master from github, installed a font package, ran your sample with pdflatex, and had no problems. The log file produced by your run should give some information for where and how pdflatex faiied.